# Where are the new desktop & server features documented?

Tags: release-management

When a new edition is coming out, I always find the new features in detail.
Not only there is Unity and cloud support, in much more detail, like sometimes Fedora used to tell when a release coming out.

New softwares, new services, solutions, many things what is changed or debut in that particular release.

I search it on www.ubuntu.com, and other sites, but didn't found. 
Is there any detailed announcement about new features ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each release has a technical overview, here's the one for 11.04

- http://www.ubuntu.com/testing

And of course, the release notes:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/releasenotes